# docker - port 80 public to docker IP

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to point a domain name to my docker container. In our router we have put port 80 forwards to `192.168.1.101` (Server Docker is running on)

The container IP address however shows up like

```
"nextjs-docker-pm2-nginx-master-nextjs-1:172.18.0.2/16"
"nextjs-docker-pm2-nginx-master-nginx-1:172.18.0.4/16"
```

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                      NAMES
cabb3c8fe03c   nextjs-docker-pm2-nginx-master_nginx    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   nextjs-docker-pm2-nginx-master-nginx-1
ed27e0fd2f24   nextjs-docker-pm2-nginx-master_nextjs   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   3000/tcp                                   nextjs-docker-pm2-nginx-master-nextjs-1
```

and my default.conf is

```
# Cache zone
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;

upstream nextjs {
  server nextjs:3000;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    server_name local.DOMAIN.com.au;
    server_tokens off;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    # BUILT ASSETS (E.G. JS BUNDLES)
    # Browser cache - max cache headers from Next.js as build id in url
    # Server cache - valid forever (cleared after cache "inactive" period)
    location /_next/static {
      proxy_cache STATIC;
      proxy_pass http://nextjs;
    }

    # STATIC ASSETS (E.G. IMAGES)
    # Browser cache - "no-cache" headers from Next.js as no build id in url
    # Server cache - refresh regularly in case of changes
    location /static {
      proxy_cache STATIC;
      proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
      proxy_cache_valid 60m;
      proxy_pass http://nextjs;
    }

    # DYNAMIC ASSETS - NO CACHE
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://nextjs;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl http2;

    server_name local.DOMAIN.com.au;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/local.domain.com.au/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/local.domain.com.au/privkey.pem;
    
       location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    # BUILT ASSETS (E.G. JS BUNDLES)
    # Browser cache - max cache headers from Next.js as build id in url
    # Server cache - valid forever (cleared after cache "inactive" period)
    location /_next/static {
      proxy_cache STATIC;
      proxy_pass http://nextjs;
    }

    # STATIC ASSETS (E.G. IMAGES)
    # Browser cache - "no-cache" headers from Next.js as no build id in url
    # Server cache - refresh regularly in case of changes
    location /static {
      proxy_cache STATIC;
      proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
      proxy_cache_valid 60m;
      proxy_pass http://nextjs;
    }

    # DYNAMIC ASSETS - NO CACHE
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://nextjs;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

our docker-compose file is

```
version: '3'
services:
  nextjs: 
    build: ./DRN1Git
  nginx: 
    user: $UID
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Docker creates an internal network. (`172.18.0.0/16` in your  case). You need to map the port of the container to the outside of your docker host (`192.168.1.101`). See [ports in compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) for reference.
E.g.:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: nginx
      ports:
      - "80:80"
```

If you provide your `docker-compose.yml` file, I will fit the example to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks for that - I am still getting an issue with allowing users to upload files.